# one-liner to cancel all sbatch jobs after a certain time or job id?

Tags: slurm

Often I need to cancel all jobs created after a certain time or job id.  Is there some syntax like `scancel -j -gt <myid>` or `scancel -j $(< some call to sacct to get jobs after time "T">)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that "> job id" is simple:

```
squeue -u $USER | awk '{if (NR!=1 && $1 > 8122014) {print $1}}' | xargs -n 1 scancel
```